# Laravel/php Three Legged OAuth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth

I want to use the [Immobilienscout Api](https://api.immobilienscout24.de/api-docs/authentication/introduction/) but I'm struggeling to get the authentication done since it uses a three-legged OAuth. I can only find oauth1 and oauth2 packages on the web for laravel and there is only one deprecated php sdk from the developers out there. Does someone know how to connect to a 3-legged oauth api through laravel/php?

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not simply use Guzzle or the Laravel Http facade? Basically, you need to make some requests to the server using http, and you need to define 1 route which the oauth server uses to redirect the user after authentication.